# I want to display Account and its related Contact Names in Table. It is displaying accountNames but not contactNames by using wrapper class I tried

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can someone help me how to display Contact Names in table related to Account Name?

html File

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <template if:true={isData}>
        
            <lightning-datatable
            key-field="isData.Id"                
            data={isData}
            columns={columns}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        
    </template> 
    <template if:true={isError}>
        <p>NO DATA RECIVED</p>
    </template>        

</lightning-card>    
</template>
```

Jsfile >>>

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getdetails from '@salesforce/apex/GetData.getdetails';

const columns = [
{ label: 'AccountName', fieldName: 'AccountName' },
{ label: 'ContactName', fieldName: 'ContactName' },   
];

export default class DisplayCaseContactAccountDetails extends LightningElement {

columns = columns;
isData;


@wire(getdetails)
wiredData({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
    this.isData = data;
    console.log('Data is', this.isData);    
    } 
    else if (error) {
   
    console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}
}
```

Apex class >>>>

```
public with sharing class GetData {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static list<CaseContactAccountWrapper> getdetails(){
    
    List<CaseContactAccountWrapper> wrappercase = new List<CaseContactAccountWrapper> ();

    List<Account> accountlist = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Name from Contacts) from Account LIMIT 15];

    for(Account acc : accountlist) {
    CaseContactAccountWrapper caseContactAccWrapper = new CaseContactAccountWrapper();

    caseContactAccWrapper.AccountName = acc.Name;
    caseContactAccWrapper.contactList = acc.contacts;
    List<String> ConName = new List<String>();
     for(Contact con : acc.Contacts){
        ConName.add(con.Name);
     }
     caseContactAccWrapper.ContactName = ConName; 
    wrappercase.add(caseContactAccWrapper);
    }
    
    return wrappercase;

}

public class CaseContactAccountWrapper{

    @AuraEnabled
    public String AccountName{get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> ContactName{get;set;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each account name is associated with a list of contact names, but the Lightning data table doesn't support this structure. If you want to display contact names in the Lightning data table, you need to represent them as a **single JSON string** for each account name. This will allow them to be shown in the table, albeit increasing the row size.

Alternatively, if you intend to display a list of contacts for each account name, consider using the **lightning-tree-grid** component in Salesforce or creating a custom table using HTML and CSS.